# Why is my API call for drug.active_ingredients.name.exact not working? (Animal and Veterinary endpoint)

Tags: api, openfda, uses-of-open-data

I am trying to look up data on the ingredient milbemycin oxime, and I want results that contain only milbemycin oxime as the active ingredient.

[https://api.fda.gov/animalandveterinary/event.json?search=drug.active_ingredients.name.exact:"milbemycin+oxime"&limit=1000](https://api.fda.gov/animalandveterinary/event.json?search=drug.active_ingredients.name.exact:%22milbemycin+oxime%22&limit=1000)

returns 0 results. This cannot be the case as there are several pet medicines with milbemycin oxime as the sole active ingredient for which I know adverse reaction events have been reported.

I also tried "spinosad" (Comfortis single active ingredient) and again 0 results.

However, there are many results when a query allows for multiple active ingredients.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://api.fda.gov/animalandveterinary/event.json?search=drug.active_ingredients.name.exact:%22Milbemycin%20Oxime%22&limit=1000 (capitalization counts). You can also remove the .exact to get results

Comment: right, but the point is to get results with only the single ingredient. And if you remove the .exact, then all AEs with any drugs containing that ingredient are returned, which is way too many to manually sort through. Also, they are generic ingredients, so no capitalization necessary

Comment: The link I gave works to get the data you want. Apparently, 'exact' requires capitalization

Answer (score 1):

I'm Violet Wren, Senior Engineer on the openFDA team. In this case, @barrycarter is correct that .exact is case sensitive. The feature you're looking for - returning results with *only* one active ingredient (the one you're searching for) is not currently possible within our API. However, I'll add this feature request to the queue and review the possibility of enhancing the API with this behavior.

Thanks,
Vi (they/she)